# How does an unsigned integer and literal get compared in C?

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

I'm doing the following comparison:

```
uint32_t value = 1000;

if(value < 100)
{
  // do something
}
```

What get's casted to what in this case? Does 'value' get casted to an integer? Does 100 get casted to an integer or unsigned integer?

Comment: Detail: C identifies `1000` as a _constant_, not a _literal_ - perhaps you are thinking of another language?.  So far, C's _literals_ (string and compound) can have their address taken, not so with 1000.

Comment: Minor: No _casting_ occurs.   `1000` is _coverted_ though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, all numeric constant have a type.  In the case of the constant `100`, because it is decimal, has no suffix, and can fit in the range of an `int`, the constant has type `int`.

How the comparison is performed is dictated by the **usual arithmetic conversions**.  Specifically, the conversion rules for integer types are specified in section 6.3.1.8p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) as follows:

> ...  the  integer  promotions  are  performed  on  both  operands.
>   Then  the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
> - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
> - Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer  types,  the  operand  with  the  type  of  lesser 
>     integer  conversion  rank  is converted to the type of the operand
>     with greater rank.
> - Otherwise,  if  the  operand  that  has  unsigned  integer  type  has  rank  greater  or equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the 
>     other  operand,  then  the  operand  with signed  integer  type  is 
>     converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned integer
>     type.
> - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>     integer type, then the  operand  with  unsigned  integer  type  is 
>     converted  to  the  type  of  the operand with signed integer type.
> - Otherwise,   both   operands   are   converted   to   the   unsigned   integer   type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed
>     integer type

Assuming an `int` on your platform is 32 bits, that makes `uint32_t` the same as an `unsigned int`, so you're using a signed type and an unsigned type of the same size in an expression.  That being the case, the third bullet point above applies, namely the value 100 (which has type `int`) is converted to an `unsigned int` and then the values are compared.

In this case, the value `100` is also within the range of an `unsigned int`, so there is no conversion of the actual value.  If it was instead something like `-100`, that value is not in the range of an `unsigned int`, which means the value would be converted to be within that range.  Again, assuming a 32 bit `int` the value would be 2<sup>32</sup> - 100.

Answer (score 0):

If two integer expressions have the same rank as in your example provided that the type uint32_t is an alias for the type unsigned int then the signed type is converted to the unsigned type.  That is the integer literal 100 that has the type signed int is converted to the type unsigned int.

From the C Standard (6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers)

> — The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the
>   corresponding signed integer type, if any.

And (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type